# Changing color of a shape on screen using a color picker without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, color-picker

I am developing a programme in javascript using D3. I have loaded a shape to the browser. 
Now I want to change the color of that shape by letting the user select the color from a color picker.
Is there any pure JS solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd break it down into:

1) Use a click event handler (D3 or jQuery, or pure JavaScript) to read the value of the color.

2) Assign the color value to the shape you've drawn using `.attr()` or `.style()`.

Hopefully this simple fiddle might be along the lines of what your intentions: http://jsfiddle.net/wg360abt/1/

Note, this doesn't follow the usual enter/update/exit pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
<head>
    <style>
        #shape{
            border:1px solid;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function update(){
            var shape = document.getElementById("shape")
            var col = document.getElementById("col")
            shape.style.backgroundColor = col.value
        }
        document.addEventListener("input",function(e){
            if(e.target.id == "col"){
                update()
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "color" id = "col" />
    <div id = "shape"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified approach of the above answer. Hope this could help you:

`<input type="color" name="favcolor" value="#cccccc" id="color_pick" onchange="setColor();"/>`

In the function you can set the colour by using the selector.

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/d_dash/j5Lndom8/